# Failure to Knit kableExtra not loading

Tags: r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I am having an issue with a program I am trying to knit in R Studio(RStudio 2023.06.0+421 "Mountain Hydrangea" Release (583b465ecc45e60ee9de085148cd2f9741cc5214, 2023-06-05) for windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.06.0+421 Chrome/110.0.5481.208 Electron/23.3.0 Safari/537.36). This program has run for months without issue and recently began failing to knit. When running chunk by chunk the code produces no errors, but when knitting the following error is produced.

```
processing file: Jail-Inspection-App.Rmd
                                                                                                             

Quitting from lines 39-51 [setup] (Jail-Inspection-App.Rmd)
Error:
! package or namespace load failed for 'kableExtra':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'kableExtra', details:
  call: !is.null(rmarkdown::metadata$output) && rmarkdown::metadata$output %in% 
  error: 'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
Backtrace:
 1. base::library(kableExtra)
 2. base::tryCatch(...)
 3. base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 4. base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 5. value[[3L]](cond)
Execution halted
```

I have reloaded, removed, reinstalled, and updated all of the libraries, always receiving the same error.

I have reloaded, removed, reinstalled, and updated all of the libraries, always receiving the same error. I am expecting it to knit as it has done in the past